# Issues creating XlsxWriter chart

Tags: python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I want to show the chart of erreur, from 1 to 100, and nb_mesure. I can't find what the error it throws means.

This is the whole code:

```
#coding=utf-8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

import xlsxwriter
import random

# Créater un tableau et  un fiche
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('tableau.xlsx')
worksheeta= workbook.add_worksheet()
worksheetb= workbook.add_worksheet()

#Fixer le numbre de mesure et le critère
Nb_Mesures = 100
critere = 0.03

#Différer la forme
format=workbook.add_format()    
format.set_border(1)  

format_ave=workbook.add_format()    
format_ave.set_bold()  
format_ave.set_align('center')


format_num=workbook.add_format()
format_num.set_num_format('0.00')   
format_num.set_align('center')

#créerer le worksheeta
worksheeta.write('A1', 'Nb_Mesures', format_ave)
worksheeta.write('B1', 'angle_aleatoire', format_ave)
worksheeta.write('C1', 'angle_mesuré',format_ave)
worksheeta.write('D1','erreur',format_ave)

worksheeta.set_column(0, 1, 13)
worksheeta.set_column(1, 1, 15)
worksheeta.set_column(2, 1, 20)
worksheeta.set_column(3, 1, 10)

#Insérer le data
data1 = []
data2 = []
data3 = []
data4 = []

sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
sum3 = 0

for row in range(1, Nb_Mesures + 1):
    b = random.randrange(0, 360)
    c = b*(1+0.02)
    d = ( - b * 0.02)
    sum1 += b
    sum2 += c
    sum3 += d
    data1.append(row)
    data2.append(b)
    data3.append(c)
    data4.append(d)

ave1 = sum1 / Nb_Mesures
ave2 = sum2 / Nb_Mesures
ave3 = sum3 / Nb_Mesures

#Ecrir les data dans le tableau
worksheeta.write_column('A2', data1, format_ave)
worksheeta.write_column('B2' ,data2, format_num)
worksheeta.write_column('C2', data3,  format_num)
worksheeta.write_column('D2', data4, format_num)
worksheeta.write('A102', 'Average', format_ave)
worksheeta.write('B102', ave1, format_num)
worksheeta.write('C102', ave2, format_num)
worksheeta.write('D102', ave3, format_num)

#créer un schéma,below code has the problem
charta  = workbook.add_chart({'type' : 'line'})

def chart_series(cur_clo):
        charta.add_series({

            'values': '=Sheeta!$D$'+cur_clo+':$D$'+cur_clo,
            })

for cline in range(2 , 101):
    chart_series(str(cline))

worksheeta.insert_chart('F2',charta)
charta.set_size({'width': 1000, 'height': 500})

workbook.close()
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace of the error you are receiving?

Comment: You can't expect us to run unknown code, please include at least the error message and the expected result. Do this by editing your post, not by commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two error in this program:

1. You are referring to a sheet named `Sheeta` which isn't created: the program creates the Excel default `Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, etc.
2. You are creating a chart series for every point on the chart.

Also, when generating a chart series programmatically it is better to use the list syntax rather than the string syntax. Replacing your `add_series()` call and function with the following should fix these errors:

```
charta.add_series({
    'values': ['Sheet1', 1, 3, 100, 3],
})
```

If you are getting started then see the [Working with Charts](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/working_with_charts.html) and [Chart Examples](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/chart_examples.html) sections of the documentation.